# Getting a value with a String[][] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

So, I'm using a String[][] to categorize objects, and, I'm having trouble getting values from it, could someone help?

Example :

```
    String[][] firstevolutiondata = {

        {"Pikachu", "Electric", "1", "Kanto", "Yellow", "35", "55", "90", "40", "Thunderstone", "1"},
        {"Charmander", "Fire", "1", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "39", "52", "65", "43", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Bulbasaur", "Grass", "1", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "45", "49", "45", "49", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Squirtle", "Water", "2", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "44", "43", "65", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Cyndaquil", "Fire", "2", "Johto", "Silver, Crystal, Gold, Heart Gold, Soul Silver", "39", "52", "65", "43", "Level 14", "1"},
        {"Chikorita", "Grass", "2", "Johto", "Silver, Crystal, Gold, Heart Gold, Soul Silver", "45", "49", "45", "65", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Totodile", "Water", "2", "Johto", "Silver, Crystal, Gold, Heart Gold, Soul Silver", "50", "65", "43", "64", "Level 18", "1"},
        {"Torchic", "Fire", "3", "Hoenn", "Sapphire, Ruby, Emerald, Omega Ruby, Alpha Sapphire", "45", "60", "45", "40", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Treecko", "Grass", "3", "Hoenn", "Sapphire, Ruby, Emerald, Omega Ruby, Alpha Sapphire", "40", "45", "70", "35", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Mudkip", "Water", "3", "Hoenn", "Sapphire, Ruby, Emerald, Omega Ruby, Alpha Sapphire", "50", "70", "40", "50", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Chimchar", "Fire", "4", "Sinnoh", "Diamond, Pearl, Platinum", "44", "58", "61", "44", "Level 14", "1"},
        {"Turtwig", "Grass", "4", "Sinnoh", "Diamond, Pearl, Platinum", "55", "68", "31", "64", "Level 18", "1"},
        {"Piplup", "Water", "4", "Sinnoh", "Diamond, Pearl, Platinum", "53", "51", "40", "53", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Tepig", "Fire", "5", "Unova", "Black, White, Black 2, White 2", "65", "63", "45", "45", "Level 17", "1"},
        {"Snivy", "Grass", "5", "Unova", "Black, White, Black 2, White 2", "45", "45", "63", "55", "Level 17", "1"},
        {"Oshawott", "Water", "5", "Unova", "Black, White, Black 2, White 2", "55", "55", "45", "45", "Level 17", "1"},
        {"Fennekin", "Fire", "6", "Kalos", "X, Y", "40", "45", "60", "40", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Chespin", "Grass", "6", "Kalos", "X, Y", "56", "61", "38", "65", "Level 16", "1"},
        {"Froakie", "Water", "6", "Kalos", "X, Y", "41", "56", "71", "40", "Level 16", "1"},

    };
```

Now, would I get the word "Pikachu"? [ For example ]

Comment: easy to implement. give yourself a try.

Comment: `firstevolutiondata[0][0]` that´s how, but i doubt that a `String[][]` is the perfect data structure for it. It´s rather that there should be a class `Pokemon` and a `List<Pokemon>` or `Map<String,Pokemon>` to store the data.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, cased closed, and, I'll look into that, thanks! :D

Comment: How do you get the word `"Pikachu"`? Easy: type it as a string literal. I suspect that you really want to get the `String[]` in which `"Pikachu"` is the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`firstevolutiondata[0][0];`would return the word "Pikachu".

Answer (score 0):

The way to look at your 2 dimensional array is as follows;

```
firstevolutiondata[0] =  new String[] {"Pikachu", "Electric", "1", "Kanto", "Yellow", "35", "55", "90", "40", "Thunderstone", "1"}
firstevolutiondata[1] =  new String[] {"Charmander", "Fire", "1", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "39", "52", "65", "43", "Level 16", "1"}
```

So if you want to access "Pikachu" you are saying I want the first index of `firstevolutiondata`, this gives you a `String[]`. You then need to get the first index of that array.

So by writing `firstevolutiondata[0][0]` you would be saying I want the first index of `firstevolutiondata`, this points to the array of strings which contains the "Pikachu" `String`. I then need to get the first index of that array to get the `String` "Pikachu".

Reconsider your design and you will find it much easier to retrieve/handles the data. Consider wrapping up the details of each `Pokemon` in its own class

```
public class Pokemon {

    public enum Type { WATER, FIRE, ... };

    private String name;
    private Type type;
    ... // Other fields like level etc.

    // Constructor / Getters & Setters
}
```

You could then have a `List` of `Pokemon` and extract what you need from the list.

If you are using Java 8 then you can use a stream and collect what you want with a filter which would look something along the lines of:

```
List<Pokemon> waterPokemonList = fullPokemonList.stream().filter(p -> p.getType() == Pokemon.Type.WATER).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you're welcome. if this answers your question please consider accepting it :)

Comment: My program is actually almost done, and, thanks to you, it can filter out all the data!